# I have one Google account for analytics, Google and plus, plus another account for adwords can I merge them?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-adsense

I wish to keep both accounts so my colleague doesn’t have to assign me permissions again. I wish to do this so I can synchronise my Google+ with website but it won’t let me with the different rights.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is to allow your main account to access all the other google accounts. When you sign into your main account, you can click near your email address, select "switch accounts" (provided that multiple accounts is turned on), and load into a different account.

Answer (score 0):

How do I invite someone to access my account?

You can invite others to gain access to your account from the Account access page. These invited users sign in to your account with their own logins, so you can safeguard your own login information.

To send an invitation, follow these steps:

- Sign in to your AdWords account at http://adwords.google.com
- Click the My Account tab.
- Select Account access.
- Click Invite other users.
- Enter the email address and name of the person you want to invite.
- Select the access level you want to assign the user. If you select Email only access, you can also choose the type of notification emails the user should receive.
- Click Send invitation.

Once the user accepts (or declines) the invitation, you'll be notified via email. If the user accepts, you'll need to grant the user access to the account before he or she can sign in. If you send the invitation to the wrong email, you can easily withdraw the invitation. If the user doesn't accept or decline the invitation within a few days, we encourage you to call him or her.